# x11vnc connection dropping unexpectedly

Tags: python, x11, vnc

I'm using [vnc_virtual_display_linker](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker) to connect PCs/tablets to use as a secondary monitor. When I run the script and connect (using [bVNC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiordanov.freebVNC&hl=en_US&gl=US) on Android), It work for a couple of minutes and fail with the following error.

What could be the source of the issue and How can I circumvent it?

**ERROR:**

```
caught XIO error:
09/11/2020 17:47:26 deleted 43 tile_row polling images.
```

**Full Log:**

```
09/11/2020 17:47:18 Got connection from client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:18   0 other clients
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Normal socket connection
09/11/2020 17:47:19 guessed desktop: gnome
09/11/2020 17:47:19 guessed dbus: 
09/11/2020 17:47:19 running pipe:

   gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/background/primary_color

09/11/2020 17:47:19 running pipe:

   gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/background/picture_options

09/11/2020 17:47:19 running command:

   gconftool-2 --set --type string /desktop/gnome/background/primary_color 'cyan4'

09/11/2020 17:47:19 running command:

   gconftool-2 --set --type string /desktop/gnome/background/picture_options 'none'

09/11/2020 17:47:19 incr accepted_client=1 for 192.168.0.56:60956  sock=10
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Client Protocol Version 3.8
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
09/11/2020 17:47:19 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 2
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Pixel format for client 192.168.0.56:
09/11/2020 17:47:19   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
09/11/2020 17:47:19   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
09/11/2020 17:47:19 no translation needed
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Using compression level 6 for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Using image quality level 7 for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Using JPEG subsampling 0, Q86 for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Enabling cursor position updates for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Enabling ExtDesktopSize protocol extension for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Using tight encoding for client 192.168.0.56
09/11/2020 17:47:19 Sending rfbEncodingExtDesktopSize for size (1366x768) 
09/11/2020 17:47:19 client_set_net: 192.168.0.56  0.0095
09/11/2020 17:47:19 created   xdamage object: 0x3e0002f
09/11/2020 17:47:19 client 1 network rate 627.6 KB/sec (21788.5 eff KB/sec)
09/11/2020 17:47:19 client 1 latency:  22.1 ms
09/11/2020 17:47:19 dt1: 0.0205, dt2: 0.1831 dt3: 0.0221 bytes: 120875
09/11/2020 17:47:19 link_rate: LR_UNKNOWN - 22 ms, 627 KB/s
09/11/2020 17:47:20 copy_tiles: allocating first_line at size 44
caught XIO error:
09/11/2020 17:47:26 deleted 43 tile_row polling images.



Press ENTER to continue
```

I am using Python 3.8.6 on Arch Linux

Comment: Did you try raising an issue on https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker project (even if it is not maintained anymore) ?

I never heard about this project. But it just look like to do wrapping above `xrandr` command. Did you try settings some keep alive ? Using `ServerAliveInterval` SSH option ?

Comment: @arthurlm Thanks for your reply. I assumed I shouldn't open a new issue since the library is unmaintained. I'll create one shortly, thanks. From what I can understand, it uses `x11vnc` to create a server so that the second monitors (pc, tablets) can connect to it. where do I set `ServerAliveInterval` option?

Comment: The `ServerAliveInterval` is an option you might set in your `~/.ssh/config` file.
I believe issue comes from a connection timeout / missing heartbeat.
I do not know how you are connecting to the remote server, and I guess you are using X11 over SSH.
But my guess / answer might also be completely unrelated.

BTW: Did you have a look at this issue https://superuser.com/questions/407218/why-does-ssh-x-forwarding-timeout-after-a-while ?